# libGDX - Rendering issue with Tiled

Tags: java, libgdx, render, tiled

For some reason as I run away the blocks behind me at the edge of the screen disappear. It is hard to get a shot of them doing that because it is different each frame, but this is what it looks like:

[image]

If someone could please tell me why its doing this that would be awesome :)

```
public void show() {
    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("assets/maps/map.tmx");

    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
    sr = new ShapeRenderer();
    sr.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    Gdx.gl.glLineWidth(3);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
}

public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.position.set(player.getX() + player.getWidth() / 2, player.getY() + player.getHeight() / 2, 0);
    camera.update();

    renderer.setView(camera);

    renderer.render(background);

    renderer.getSpriteBatch().begin();
    player.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());
    renderer.getSpriteBatch().end();

    renderer.render(foreground);

    // render objects
    sr.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    for(MapObject object : map.getLayers().get("objects").getObjects())
        if(object instanceof RectangleMapObject) {
            RectangleMapObject rectObject = (RectangleMapObject) object;
            Rectangle rect = rectObject.getRectangle();
            if(rectObject.getProperties().containsKey("gid")) { // if it contains the gid key, it's an image object from Tiled
                int gid = rectObject.getProperties().get("gid", Integer.class);
                TiledMapTile tile = map.getTileSets().getTile(gid);
                renderer.getSpriteBatch().begin();
                renderer.getSpriteBatch().draw(tile.getTextureRegion(), rect.x, rect.y);
                renderer.getSpriteBatch().end();
            } else { // otherwise, it's a normal RectangleMapObject
                sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
                sr.rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
                sr.end();
            }
        } else if(object instanceof CircleMapObject) {
            Circle circle = ((CircleMapObject) object).getCircle();
            sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
            sr.circle(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius);
            sr.end();
        } else if(object instanceof EllipseMapObject) {
            Ellipse ellipse = ((EllipseMapObject) object).getEllipse();
            sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
            sr.ellipse(ellipse.x, ellipse.y, ellipse.width, ellipse.height);
            sr.end();
        } else if(object instanceof PolylineMapObject) {
            Polyline line = ((PolylineMapObject) object).getPolyline();
            sr.begin(ShapeType.Line);
            sr.polyline(line.getTransformedVertices());
            sr.end();
        } else if(object instanceof PolygonMapObject) {
            Polygon poly = ((PolygonMapObject) object).getPolygon();
            sr.begin(ShapeType.Line);
            sr.polygon(poly.getTransformedVertices());
            sr.end();
        }
}
```

Comment: What map renderer are you using?

Comment: Im using libGDX graphics, OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer

Comment: Try switching to `OrthoCahedTiledMaprenderer` to see if the problem still occurs. Also, please post the function in which you render the map. Are there any other `SpriteBatch` instances besides the one used by the map renderer?

Comment: There is no OrthoCahedTiledMaprenderer and there is only 1 instance of spritebatch, I am editing the post to put in the function

Comment: Here's the API documentation for [*OrthoCachedTiledMapRenderer*](http://bit.ly/1rk0RGk); you might be using an older version of LibGDX. Also, you should know that you are, in fact, using two *SpriteBatch* instances because the renderer creates its own. I'm not saying this would fix your problem, but if you wanted the renderer to not create its own *SpriteBatch*, [you can pass one in its constructor](http://bit.ly/1qvJvtO).

Comment: Im pretty sure I am using an older version of libGDX. Could this be affecting it?

Comment: I don't know. Unfortunately, I can't help since I never ran into this problem myself and it seems the LibGDX expertise on SO is very low. You should ask this question on the [official help forums](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=11&sid=45b6708b3711480e511b339d30b97bdd) as well, you might have more luck there. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer`.

It's working now and the tiles (bigger tiles) won't disappear:

```
    float x = orthographicCamera.position.x - orthographicCamera.viewportWidth * orthographicCamera.zoom;
    float y = orthographicCamera.position.y - orthographicCamera.viewportHeight * orthographicCamera.zoom;

    float width = orthographicCamera.viewportWidth * orthographicCamera.zoom * 2;
    float height = orthographicCamera.viewportHeight * orthographicCamera.zoom * 2;

    orthogonalTiledMapRenderer.setView(orthographicCamera.combined, x, y, width, height);
```